# How can I find a non-prime number whose square root is irrational?

Tags: prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

I already know that when $n$ is prime, that $\sqrt n$ is irrational (this is true in every case), but I know that this isn't only true for primes, $\sqrt 8$ is irrational, but it's not a prime number.

So how could I find numbers like these, where it's square root is an irrational number, but yet it's not prime?

Comment: Take any two non-identical primes, multiply them, and the square root of the result will be irrational.  You can then start building on that to find _all_ such numbers...all you have to do is make sure that there is an _odd_ number of _at least one_ prime factor.

Comment: I saw your comment at dxvi's answer, he answered exactly what needs to be done. Perhaps you want some kind of *formula* that generate such numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

---

[ EDIT ]    Examples of such non-prime $n$ whose square root is irrational:

- any non-prime integer whose prime factorization includes a prime at an odd power;
- $m!\;$ for any $\;m \gt 2$;
- $m^2 - 1\;$ for any $\;m \gt 2$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I wasn't asking that, I wanted to know how to find a non-prime number whose square root is irrational.

Comment: @Flostin That's precisely what the hint points at. Just pick any non-prime integer which is *not* a perfect square. Equivalently, any non-prime integer whose prime factorization includes a prime at an odd power.